# Get Started Button

Tags: bots, messenger

I am administrator of a facebook page in which a messenger bot is integrated. When  I am logging in from my account, I am getting the GET STARTED the button. But when a different person is trying to start a chat with the bot, it is not getting the GET STARTED BUTTON. Please help what needs to done.

code used to get the GET STARTED BUTTON:

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "get_started": {"payload": "USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"}
}' https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=

Answer (score 0):

Change the payload value to `get_started`

[image]